# (Legacy) MFCOM VBScript gets Invalid Procedure Call

Tags: vbscript, citrix

I can list all published apps just fine, that works, but when trying to get the root applications folder I get an invalid procedure call. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
Dim theFarm,rootAppFolder
Set oWSHShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set oWSHNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set oWSHProcEnv = oWSHSHELL.Environment("PROCESS")

            'Create MetaFrameFarm object
            Set theFarm = CreateObject("MetaFrameCOM.MetaFrameFarm")
              if Err.Number <> 0 Then
                WScript.Echo "Can't create MetaFrameFarm object"
                WScript.Echo "(" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description
                WScript.Echo ""
                WScript.Quit Err.Number
              End if


            'Initialize the farm object.
            theFarm.Initialize 1

          If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                WScript.Echo "Can't  Initialize MetaFrameFarm object"
                WScript.Echo "(" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description
                WScript.Echo ""
                WScript.Quit Err.Number
              End if

Set rootAppFolder = theFarm.GetRootFolder(MetaFrameAppFolder) 'error on this line here
Set appFolder = rootAppFolder.GetSubFolder("A_USA")
Set folder = appFolder.AppFolder

For each app in folder.Applications

    app.LoadData(0)
    WScript.Echo app.AppName

Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Option Explicit` to avoid blunders like an un-initialized `MetaFrameAppFolder`.

Comment: What is option explicit. For some reason it worked when I put the number 12 there instead of MetaFrameAppFolder. Now I'm realizing that should have been set as a constant.